# BPEL Managed server Error

Tags: weblogic, bpel

***Issue is resolved.
I changed the data source driver to non XA and its working fine
thanks***

I am seeing this error in Bpel managed server log. something related to Quartz scheduler. has anybody seen this error ?

Is bpel expecting some database tables to be empty for persistance

this is the stack trace i see, nothing seems to related to the application.

```
<Apr 4, 2013 11:13:35 AM PDT> <Error> <oracle.integration.platform.blocks.scheduler.FabricJobStoreCMT> <BEA-000000> <ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: null
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at $Proxy364.commit(Unknown Source)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.commitConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3621)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3210)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3811)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:3798)
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:621)
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:456)
        at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:147)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy318.start(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.scheduler.QrtzSchedulerServiceImpl.startScheduler(QrtzSchedulerServiceImpl.java:46)
        at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.scheduler.FabricSchedulerFactory.stateChanged(FabricSchedulerFactory.java:147)
        at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.FabricLifecycle.notifyListeners(FabricLifecycle.java:46)
        at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.FabricLifecycle.setState(FabricLifecycle.java:30)
        at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.MeshImpl.postDeployInit(MeshImpl.java:118)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at oracle.integration.platform.metrics.PhaseEventAspect.invoke(PhaseEventAspect.java:71)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy304.postDeployInit(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.integration.platform.kernel.FabricKernelInitializerServlet$1.run(FabricKernelInitializerServlet.java:555)
        at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.executor.WorkManagerExecutor$1.run(WorkManagerExecutor.java:120)
        at weblogic.work.j2ee.J2EEWorkManager$WorkWithListener.run(J2EEWorkManager.java:183)
        at weblogic.work.DaemonWorkThread.run(DaemonWorkThread.java:30)
Caused By: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

Comment: if the issue is resolved, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

BPEL is expecting the **RCU** tables to be created and accessible on the Database.

Did you properly created the RCU schemas? Can you check in WEblogic that the `SOADataSource` is correctly defined and that you can access it from Admin/BPEL-managed servers?

Also, is seems like the error is related to your cluster configuration : `ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: null`.